# How to Display view more option on Dynamically created table data using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, servlets

My In Ajax call success I am building a table and filling data with values received responseJson.

Sometimes my table td may contain paragraph, on that situation I want to display first 5 characters followed with view more link,then if the user want to see the full message by pressing the link it will be visible.

My code is:

```
                   if(responseJson!=null){
                    $("#gnotes").hide(); 

                                     $("#table2").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                                 var table1 = $("#table2");
                                 $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
       var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
       rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['date']); 
       rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['name']); 
       var msg_size = value['message'].length;
       var msg = value['message'];

       if(msg_size > 20 )
        {
            rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['message']);
    //rowNew.children().eq(2).append($("<input />", {"type": "button", "value": "Clickto view", "onclick":"Display("+msg+")"}));

        }
         if(msg_size <= 20 )
        {
           rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['message']); 

        }
        rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['createdon']); 

    rowNew.attr("class","info");
     rowNew.appendTo(table1);
       });
    }
              $("#table2").show();
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by doing

```
           $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
              var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td> 
                             <td></td></tr>");
              rowNew.children().eq(0).text(moment(value['createdon']).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')); 
              rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['name']); 
                     var msg_size = value['message'].length;
                     var msg = value['message'];
                     var msg1 = msg.slice(0,8);
                     var putmsg = value['message'];
                     var fileid = value['id'];
                     var msg2 = "  viewmore...";
                     msg2 =   msg2.fontcolor("blue");
                     var msg3 = msg1.concat(msg2);
                     if(msg_size > 20 )
                         {
                                rowNew.children().eq(2).html(msg3);
                                var $row = rowNew.children().eq(2);
                                $row.closest('td').addClass('checked');
                                $row.closest('td').attr('id',msg);
                         }
                     if(msg_size <= 20 )
                         {

                           rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['message']); 

                         }
             rowNew.children().eq(3).append($("<input />", {"type": "button","value" : "Print" , "class":"viewlist", "onclick":"printGnotesMessage("+fileid+")"})); 
             rowNew.attr("class","info");
             rowNew.appendTo(table1);
           });
```

and we can change the names and ID of that particular td element by cheking class selector of td

```
          $( "#tableID tbody").on( "click","tr.info td.checked", function() {
                var id=$(this).attr('id').toString();
                var string1 = "  viewless...";
                    string1 = string1.fontcolor("blue");
                    id = id.concat(string1);
                    $(this).html(id);
                    $(this).attr('class','viewless');

           });

     $( "#tableID tbody").on( "click","tr.info td.viewless", function() {

            var id=$(this).attr('id').toString();
                id = id.slice(0,8);
            var string1 = "  viewmore...";
                string1 = string1.fontcolor("blue");
                id = id.concat(string1);
                $(this).html(id);
                $(this).attr('class','checked');

        });
```